# ejabberd users store in which mnesia tables?

Tags: ejabberd, mnesia

I am new to ejabberd, i successfully connected to pidgin(xmpp messenger) and creating users from there.
It is created on my ejabberd server also, by default ejabberd using mnesia database.

I would like to know, which are the table's ejabberd using to store the users in mnesia. And i tried the following command to view the mnesia table.

```
tv:start()
```

This command is given error " **** exception error: undefined function tv:start/0** "

please help me....

Answer (score 0):

It means that tv application is not available. If you are using ejabberd installer, tv is indeed not included. You have to compile / install a full version of Erlang/OTP to get it.